# Check whether multiple images are uploaded to a field?

Tags: entities

Is there a way to check whether or not more than one image is uploaded to a field? I'm working on a custom node template and want a conditional to do x if only one image and y if more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it done in a few lines using the [`field_get_items`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function:

```
if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name')) {
  if (count($items) == 1) {
    // ...
  }
  elseif (count($items) > 1) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

It'd be best to keep this logic out of the template file itself and put it in a preprocess function though.